# What's the Russian for suspenders/garter belt?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, существительные

I'm looking for the specific, correct Russian translation for *suspenders/garter belt* — the kind a lady wears when she wants to be sexually provocative. I'm explicitly looking for this kind of lingerie, and not just a wardrobe accessory used to fulfill some practical function like holding up pants, for example. In German, we have the word "Strapse" — or plural "Strapsen." As far as I know, English suspenders/garter belt doesn't refer to the same thing. Suspenders is more general, and, consequently, not specific enough. Garter belt sounds weird. In Russian, I found different translations using different translators, however they're not all correct, as far as I can tell:

подтяжки

подвязка

пояс для чулок

Comment: https://defile.ru/katalog/nizhnee_bele/poyasa_podvyazki/

Comment: Is this what you mean? It is called пояс с подвязками.

Comment: could you please look up a picture of the object you're looking for and post it here?

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I did not post any pictures as I wasn't sure if I am allowed to post such things. The link you gave shows the correct item, indeed.

Comment: V.V.  Your link is bad, but I am interested in what you were trying to link us to.  Could you please provide another?

Comment: In English, this is most definitely a garter belt, and it doesn't sound "weird" to us — it sounds sexy ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for *пояс для чулок* ("garter belt").

It's a belt which is worn about the waist and has suspenders which attach to the stockings and help hold them up (or at least that's how it looks).

The belt itself and the suspenders are usually sewn together and do not detach. I'm not sure that there's a commonly used separate word just for the suspender parts, but people seem to be using *подвязки, резинки, подтяжки, держатели*.

Without a context, *подтяжки* ("suspenders") are belt suspenders which are worn over the shoulders, and *подвязка* ("garter") is a piece of leather or fabric which is worn about the leg right below the knee.

Comment: Ok, I will accept your answer, but what is пояс с подвязками? So this would be the пояс для чулок together with подвязки?

Comment: @BertHobe: it's the same thing. Looks like there's no single name for this garment everyone would use.